# How to model a record store in Haskell

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

I would like to model a record store in Haskell. Actually selling records isn't important, I would mostly like to focus on how to model inventory management and keeping track of sales. My problem description is like this:

1. Record a single sale of a track given an artist name and track title.
2. Return the total number of sales of a track given an artist name and track title.
   (This should return 0 if there is no matching track.)
3. Remove a track from the record of sales given an artist name and track title.

How do I get started?

Comment: When you ask questions on StackOverflow: Skip the "I don't know much", and make sure you inline the actual problem description; linking to an image has two problems: One problem is that it cannot be scanned easily by search engines, so others won't find your question. Another problem is that if the external image should eventually get lost, this post loses all meaning since the body of the question is void of any description besides a broken link. Lastly, the revised question is still void of any attempt. So maybe you could replace the "How do I get started?" with "Here's what I have tried" :)

Comment: Consider using lists to store current records on sales. Where each element of list would have artist, track name and sales number. 1. would update element on a list, 2. would return value when element matches artist name, 3. would remove element from list

Answer (score 1):

So first you might go over your problem description and highlight the nouns and verbs that constitute your problem domain: *sale*, *track*, *track title*, *artist*, *number of sales*, *record of sales*. I might then start off by defining a data type for what appears to be the most central concept:

```hs
import Data.Text (Text)

type Title = Text
type Artist = Text

data Track = Track
  { trackTitle :: Title
  , trackArtist :: Artist
  } deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

bestTrack, okayTrack :: Track
bestTrack = Track
  { trackTitle = "it's is my life"
  , trackArtist = "jon bovi"
  }

okayTrack = Track
  { trackTitle = "living in preyer"
  , trackArtist = "jon bovi"
  }
```

You could also define a sale in much the same way.

Maybe you want to use the [safe-money](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/safe-money) package for modelling the price.

```hs
import Money

type Price = Dense "USD"

data Sale = Sale
  { saleTrack :: Track
  , salePrice :: Price
  }

sales :: [Sale]
sales =
  [ Sale { saleTrack = bestTrack, salePrice = 399 % 100 }
  , Sale { saleTrack = okayTrack, salePrice = 284 % 100 }
  ]
```

Those were the nouns. The verbs, *add/remove a sales record*, can be made into functions. If the sales is a list, then adding and removing a sales record becomes a recursive function that operates on lists:

```hs
addSale :: Track -> Price -> [Sale] -> [Sale]
addSale soldTrack soldPrice existingSales = ...

removeSale :: Title -> [Sale] -> [Sale]
removeSale title existingSales = ...
```

In the process of writing these functions you can also test them by formulating properties about them: For example: Adding a sale to an existing list of sales, the produced list should be one sale greater. Removing a sale from an empty list of sales should either produce an error, or reproduce the empty list of sales (decide). Removing a sale from a non-empty list of sales should produce a list with one sale less. Removing a sale from a list of sales that contains the same track title twice should only remove one of them (which? decide). Adding and then removing a track should produce the same list of sales as before adding it.

From these properties you can either construct unit tests or property tests.

When you model something like a shop, you can also go deeper into good practices, for example, recording different prices for the same item is probably bad, so you may want to invent a product code. Modelling a shop well is a rabbit hole, so if you're just trying to make a silly proof-of-concept to cover most possible ground, such as eventually getting to a UI, then this part probably doesn't matter much.